# Spring tag(form : form) undefined in jsp though I am using spring taglib. Why?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>  
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>

<form :form>
</form : form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried in maven project still I got the same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of spaces in between spring `<form>` tag.

**Remove space between form tags like below.**

Change

`<form :form>` to `<form:form>`

And

`</form : form>` to `</form:form>`